# How could I load external content?

Tags: javascript

I would like to load Datastudio or Analytics reports in my app with javascript?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mydiv').load('http://datastudio.com');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load the plain content from **ANY**site. It is obvious that this will produce a security whole..

To be able to load some content from **anysite.com** to **yoursite.com**

**anysite.com** has to provide a CORS header which will allow you to share content between **anysite.com** and **yoursite.com**

Comment: I mean a site that I own the domain...

Comment: cant you just send only #external-div without the rest?